# CSS issue with using images on a right-to-left page

Tags: css, arabic, hebrew

I have radio and checkbox questions on my website that use images to replace the default browser inputs ... so I use positioning to move the input out of the way that alot of tutorials use, and then make space for the image with some padding.
But on a rtl direction page like arabic and hebrew, when you click on the radio/label.

https://jsfiddle.net/nm3fw7mx/2/ (with javascript that swaps the images)
https://jsfiddle.net/nm3fw7mx/ (simple example w/o javascript, shows same issue when click the radio/label)

Any idea how to fix this issue?
I forget for form submission in all browsers, if inputs needs to visible (and hence why I cant use display:none; or visibility: none; on the input's css?). At least thats what Im guessing since alot of tutorials back in the day recommended using positioning to do this. Here is the jist of the important css:

```
.label_radio input { position: absolute; left: -9999px; }
.page-text-direction-rtl .label_radio { 
padding-right: 25px;  
  background: transparent url(http://www.mywebsite.com/images/gui/radio_off.png)   no-repeat right 2px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did a fiddle and came up with something new, well did you try setting opacity of checkbox to zero and position it to near the image, you see you are getting a horizontal scroll in current case, we do not want that.

```
.label_radio input { 
    position: absolute; right: 30px;
    opacity:0;
}
```

and this

```
.page-text-direction-rtl /*for browsers that don't support :dir        selector */
{
  overflow:none;
  direction: rtl; /*sometimes dir attribute by itself in my ap wasn't  working, so being explicit here */
  text-align: right;
}
```

you can try the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vag4bya8/)

NOTE: the checksboxes are getting checked, it is just they are hidden, do not get confused. good luck.

Comment: For now, I'll use the opacity fix as it seems to work in all browsers.